# Unable to access Ember model data inside the controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have my controller and model. I am trying to access the model inside the controller like this
App.AssignmentController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

```
    App = Ember.Application.create({});


App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('assignment',{path:'about'});
});


App.AssignmentAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({


    findQuery: function(store, type, queryData) {

         var findQueryURL = 'http://local_env.mhhe.com/openapi/lms/coversheet/sectionid/241409387/assignmentid/14706368/userid/1000321061/isangelinstallation/false/returnUrl/bb';
         return this.ajax(findQueryURL, 'POST', {
            data: queryData.query
         })
    }

});

App.AssignmentRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.findQuery('assignment','1');
  },
});
  var attr = DS.attr;

App.Assignment = DS.Model.extend({
assignmentId: attr('number'),
sectionId:attr('number'),
assignmentType:attr('string'),
assignmentTitle:attr('string'),
assignmentStartDate:attr('string'),
assignmentStartTime:attr('string'),
assignmentDueDate:attr('string'),
assignmentDueTime:attr('string'),
isMarathonChain:attr('boolean'),
assignmentTimeLimit:attr('number'),
assignmentTimeRemaining:attr('number'),
marathonAssignmentStatus:attr('string'),
showAssignmentAttemptsAndPasswordDetails:attr('boolean'),
assignmentAttemptsTaken:attr('number'),
assignmentAttemptsAllowed:attr('number'),
showPasswordForm:attr('boolean'),
isStartAssignment:attr('boolean'),
isResumeAssignment:attr('boolean'),
isSubmitAssignment:attr('boolean'),
passwordRequired:attr('boolean'),
isConvertToGeniusEnabled:attr('boolean'),
draftNumber:attr('number'),
studentExceptionExistsForDueDate:attr('boolean'),
isPastUploadDate:attr('boolean'),
showMarathonPrerequisiteInfo:attr('boolean')
});  

App.AssignmentController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    displayAssignments: function(){
        var assignments = this.get('model.assignment');
       // i also tried this.store.find but that also didnt gave me the output 
        return assignments;

    }.property('model.assignment'),
});
```

Now i am trying to access this model inside this controller but i am unable to access it. here in this controller i will be manipulating some extra condition and use this in my template to check some condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your `model` hook expects a `promise`, `object` or `array` to be returned (you omitted the `return` statement).

```
model: function() {
  return this.store.findQuery('assignment','1');
}
```

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/

Comment: i also did this, but now also i am not getting any thing from my controller. it is returning undefined. one more thing I notice by putting debug point in that controller that when its come to that controller my model is not set and once i press F8 and comes out of it my model is set with all the value. can this be a problem ?